# Prediction without labelled data

Tags: probability, classification, predictive-models, supervised-learning, generative-models

I am working on a churn prediction model, where I am trying to predict probability of employee churn. For each employee I have the following features

1) Role 2) Total experience 3) Current experience  etc.

but I don't have labelled historical data about who churned in the past. So supervised learning is not applicable here.

What kind of approaches are useful in these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This problem falls under the category of *unsupervised learning*, in which the most common approach is *clustering:*

One tries to divide data in different groups based on the features that are given. Various approaches exist, for example *k-means* or *density-based approaches*; take a look at for example [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

Another possiblity is to perform *dimensionality reduction* in order to visualize your data. This can be done by for example [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or by constructing a [Self-Organizing Map (SOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map). The first one is a linear method (which can be extended to a non-linear method, so-called [Kernel PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis)), the second one is non-linear.